# config AMP page with analytics

Tags: amp-analytics

if this is my tage for website pages :

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxxxx');

i have  made page with AMP and i trying config with analytics but it doesn't work please any on make it for amp page and send it .

thank you for your help.

i have  made page with AMP and i trying config with analytics but it doesn't work please any on make it for amp page and send it .